# How to keep the radio button selected if the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

im trying to make multiple choice with radio button, when i selected the choice and refresh the page, the choice i have selected is reset to be empty, how to solve this? i need keep the choice i have selected

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="quiz" action="<?php echo base_url('pegawai/answer_aksi'); ?>" role="form" id="form1" method="post" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
         <div class="table-title">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Quiz Online</h2></div>
             </div>
                </div>
                <ol type="1">            
                   <?php foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
                   <?php 
                    $a=array($row->choice1,$row->choice2,$row->choice3,$row->answer);
                    shuffle($a);
                   ?>
                <li>
                <?php echo $row->soal; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id_quiz[]" value="<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>">
                <ol type="a">
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>[]" value="<?=$a[0]?>" >
                    <?=$a[0]?><br>
                  </li>
                 <li>
                     <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>[]" value="<?=$a[1]?>" >
                     <?=$a[1]?><br>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>[]" value="<?=$a[2]?>" >
                    <?=$a[2]?><br>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>[]" value="<?=$a[3]?>" >
                    <?=$a[3]?><br>
                 </li>
                </ol>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
                </ol>
            <div class="posisi">
               <button type="submit" name="enter" class="btn btn-success" >Simpan</button>
              <!-- <button type="reset" class="btn btn-white">Batal</button> -->
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can use `local storage` 
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy with PHP. You can use `isset()` inside the HTML tag for the condition to check or uncheck.

```
isset($a[0]) ? 'checked' : ''
```

Use this in the radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="jawaban<?php echo $row->id_quiz; ?>[]" value="<?=$a[0]?>" <?= isset($a[0]) ? 'checked' : ''?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain your radio values into cookies. But maintaining cookies for radio values is very difficult or you can use local storage.

Some references are given below to use cookies and local storage.

1.https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

2.https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
window.localStorage.setItem('user', 'jawaban'); //Set or save
window.localStorage.getItem('user'); //get back the saved value
```

[image]